# How to prevent error when multiple operators chosen in javascript calculator?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am a newbie making a JS calculator. It works fine, but it gets an error if you click multiple operators or the same operator more than once, but it works ok if you only click one operator.. I could not find out why, because there is nothing in console. Nothing online either. Please help...

HTML:

```
<div id="calculator" class="calculator">
<button id="clear" class="clear" onclick = "clear">AC</button>

<div id="viewer" class="viewer">0</div>

<button class="num" data-num="7">7</button>
  <button class="num" data-num="8">8</button>
  <button class="num" data-num="9">9</button>
  <button data-ops="divided by" class="ops">÷</button>

  <button class="num" data-num="4">4</button>
  <button class="num" data-num="5">5</button>
  <button class="num" data-num="6">6</button>
  <button data-ops="times" class="ops">x</button>

  <button class="num" data-num="1">1</button>
  <button class="num" data-num="2">2</button>
  <button class="num" data-num="3">3</button>
  <button data-ops="minus" class="ops">-</button>

  <button class="num zero" data-num="0">0</button>
  <button class="num" data-num=".">.</button>
  <button data-ops="plus" class="ops">+</button>
  <button id="equals" class="equals">=</button>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  // Shortcut to get elements
  var el = function(element) {
    if (element.charAt(0) === "#") { // If passed an ID...
      return document.querySelector(element); // ... returns single element
    }

    return document.querySelectorAll(element); // Otherwise, returns a nodelist
  };

  // Variables
  var viewer = el("#viewer"), // Calculator screen where result is displayed
    equals = el("#equals"), // Equal button
    nums = el(".num"), // List of numbers
    ops = el(".ops"), // List of operators
    theNum = "", // Current number
    oldNum = "", // First number
    resultNum, // Result
    operator; // Batman

  // When: Number is clicked. Get the current number selected
  var setNum = function() {
    if (resultNum) { // If a result was displayed, reset number
      theNum = this.getAttribute("data-num");
      resultNum = "";
    } else { // Otherwise, add digit to previous number (this is a string!)
      theNum += this.getAttribute("data-num");
    }

    viewer.innerHTML = theNum; // Display current number

  };

  // When: Operator is clicked. Pass number to oldNum and save operator
  var moveNum = function() {
    oldNum = theNum;
    theNum = "";
    operator = this.getAttribute("data-ops");

    equals.setAttribute("data-result", ""); // Reset result in attr
  };

  // When: Equals is clicked. Calculate result
  var displayNum = function() {

    // Convert string input to numbers
    oldNum = parseFloat(oldNum);
    theNum = parseFloat(theNum);

    // Perform operation
    switch (operator) {
      case "plus":
        resultNum = oldNum + theNum;
        break;

      case "minus":
        resultNum = oldNum - theNum;
        break;

      case "times":
        resultNum = oldNum * theNum;
        break;

      case "divided by":
        resultNum = oldNum / theNum;
        break;

        // If equal is pressed without an operator, keep number and continue
      default:
        resultNum = theNum;
    }

    // If NaN or Infinity returned
    if (!isFinite(resultNum)) {
      if (isNaN(resultNum)) { // If result is not a number; set off by, eg, double-clicking operators
        resultNum = "Error";
      } else { // If result is infinity, set off by dividing by zero
        resultNum = "Error";
        el('#calculator').classList.add("broken"); // Break calculator
      }
    }

    // Display result, finally!
    viewer.innerHTML = resultNum;
    equals.setAttribute("data-result", resultNum);

    // Now reset oldNum & keep result
    oldNum = 0;
    theNum = resultNum;

  };

  /* The click events */

  // Add click event to numbers
  for (let i = 0, l = nums.length; i < l; i++) {
    nums[i].onclick = setNum;
  }

  // Add click event to operators
  for (let i = 0, l = ops.length; i < l; i++) {
    ops[i].onclick = moveNum;
  }

  // Add click event to equal sign
  equals.onclick = displayNum;
  // When clear button is pressed clear everything
  function clear() {
    oldNum = "";
    theNum = "";
    viewer.innerHTML = "0";
    equals.setAttribute("data-result", resultNum);
  }
  el("#clear").onclick = clear;
}());
```

Comment: Also, this is the link: https://aaryank.codewizardshq.com/JSCalculator/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling this twice in a row if you click 2 operands in a row:

```
var moveNum = function() {
  oldNum = theNum;
  theNum = "";
  operator = this.getAttribute("data-ops");

  equals.setAttribute("data-result", ""); // Reset result in attr
};
```

The first 2 lines will break if you do it twice with no number changes in between - you need to verify that you have a 'theNum' value before doing those 2 lines, otherwise you will set `oldNum = theNum` the first time, then `oldNum = ""` the second

Answer (score 0):

See below example

```js
     (function() {
              "use strict";
             
              // Shortcut to get elements
              var el = function(element) {
                if (element.charAt(0) === "#") { // If passed an ID...
                  return document.querySelector(element); // ... returns single element
                }
            
                return document.querySelectorAll(element); // Otherwise, returns a nodelist
              };
            
              // Variables
              window.fixOperators = false;
              var viewer = el("#viewer"), // Calculator screen where result is displayed
                equals = el("#equals"), // Equal button
                nums = el(".num"), // List of numbers
                ops = el(".ops"), // List of operators
                theNum = "", // Current number
                oldNum = "", // First number
                resultNum, // Result
                operator; // Batman
            
              // When: Number is clicked. Get the current number selected
              var setNum = function() {
                if (resultNum) { // If a result was displayed, reset number
                  theNum = this.getAttribute("data-num");
                  resultNum = "";
                } else { // Otherwise, add digit to previous number (this is a string!)
                  theNum += this.getAttribute("data-num");
                }
            
                viewer.innerHTML = theNum; // Display current number
                window.fixOperators = false;
              };
            
              // When: Operator is clicked. Pass number to oldNum and save operator
              var moveNum = function() {
               if(window.fixOperators){
                 return;
                }
                oldNum = theNum;
                theNum = "";
                operator = this.getAttribute("data-ops");
            
                equals.setAttribute("data-result", ""); // Reset result in attr
                 window.fixOperators = true;
              };
            
              // When: Equals is clicked. Calculate result
              var displayNum = function() {
            
                // Convert string input to numbers
                oldNum = parseFloat(oldNum);
                theNum = parseFloat(theNum);
               
                // Perform operation
                switch (operator) {
                  case "plus":
                    resultNum = oldNum + theNum;
                    break;
            
                  case "minus":
                    resultNum = oldNum - theNum;
                    break;
            
                  case "times":
                    resultNum = oldNum * theNum;
                    break;
            
                  case "divided by":
                    resultNum = oldNum / theNum;
                    break;
            
                    // If equal is pressed without an operator, keep number and continue
                  default:
                    resultNum = theNum;
                  }
                
            
                // If NaN or Infinity returned
                if (!isFinite(resultNum)) {
                  if (isNaN(resultNum)) { // If result is not a number; set off by, eg, double-clicking operators
                    resultNum = "Error";
                  } else { // If result is infinity, set off by dividing by zero
                    resultNum = "Error";
                    el('#calculator').classList.add("broken"); // Break calculator
                  }
                }
            
                // Display result, finally!
                viewer.innerHTML = resultNum;
                equals.setAttribute("data-result", resultNum);
            
                // Now reset oldNum & keep result
                oldNum = 0;
                theNum = resultNum;
            
              };
            
              /* The click events */
            
              // Add click event to numbers
              for (let i = 0, l = nums.length; i < l; i++) {
                nums[i].onclick = setNum;
              }
            
              // Add click event to operators
              for (let i = 0, l = ops.length; i < l; i++) {
                ops[i].onclick = moveNum;
              }
            
              // Add click event to equal sign
              equals.onclick = displayNum;
              // When clear button is pressed clear everything
              function clear() {
                oldNum = "";
                theNum = "";
                viewer.innerHTML = "0";
                equals.setAttribute("data-result", resultNum);
              }
              el("#clear").onclick = clear;
            }());
```

```html
    <div id="calculator" class="calculator">
    <button id="clear" class="clear" onclick = "clear">AC</button>

    <div id="viewer" class="viewer">0</div>

    <button class="num" data-num="7">7</button>
      <button class="num" data-num="8">8</button>
      <button class="num" data-num="9">9</button>
      <button data-ops="divided by" class="ops">÷</button>

      <button class="num" data-num="4">4</button>
      <button class="num" data-num="5">5</button>
      <button class="num" data-num="6">6</button>
      <button data-ops="times" class="ops">x</button>

      <button class="num" data-num="1">1</button>
      <button class="num" data-num="2">2</button>
      <button class="num" data-num="3">3</button>
      <button data-ops="minus" class="ops">-</button>

      <button class="num zero" data-num="0">0</button>
      <button class="num" data-num=".">.</button>
      <button data-ops="plus" class="ops">+</button>
      <button id="equals" class="equals">=</button>
```